# Redirect to login page after a user is registered. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I redirect to login page, after a user is registered on my web application with a message called "Your information is received and witing for admin approval.". By using laravel 5.4 version

Note: I have done the login and register by using Auth procress of laravel 5.4.

Edit: Here is my RegisterController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class RegisterController extends Controller

{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/login';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'userimage' => 'required|image'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data) {
    $path = Storage::putFile('userimages',$data['userimage']);
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'userimage' => $path,
        'user_type' => 3
    ]);
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: You can change this line in your `RegisterController.php`  `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/login';`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya I have tried it, and it also redirected to login by the Url

Ex: localhost/appName/login

But the page shows "The page is not working"

Comment: Can you post whole error message here?

Comment: Try clearing cache and views

Comment: Tried. But not working.

Comment: In case you are using Apache2 make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: Well I have a Middleware called RedirectIfAuthenticated. There I have this small code. Is it doing something. public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) { if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { return redirect('/home'); } return $next($request); }

Because if I change the code redirect to login, then the page shows "Page is not working." Otherwise it take me to dashboard page, Which I done want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `RegisterController`, by default Laravel login the user, so when you redirect back to `login` route. It gives you **page is not redirecting properly** error.

In your `RegisterController` add the `register` method :

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('message', 'Your message');
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. You saved my time. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, this still work on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 2):

Also add this line of code on the top of RegisterController:

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;